# create temporary file from gridfs stream to file nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stream

I am trying to read binary file from mongodb Gridfs and write the image in pdfkit image. I have tried following code, it creates file in temp folder but the file is  empty.

```
gfs.files.findOne({"filename":"test.png"}, callback.wrap(function (image) {
   console.log(image.filename);
   temp.open({suffix: image.filename}, function (err, info) {
     if (err) {
        console.log(err);
     }
     var stream = gfs.createReadStream({_id: image._id});
     fs.write(info.fd, stream, 'binary');
     fs.close(info.fd, function () {
        //doc.image(info.path);
      });
    });
});
```

How should we write the binary image saved in gridfs to temporary file. once file is created I will pass the path to [pdfkit](http://pdfkit.org/) variable `doc`.

used packages are [node-temp](https://github.com/bruce/node-temp), [gridfs-stream](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream)

Comment: You should create a filestream and use 'pipe' to stream your data from gridfs to the file. For example:
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
stream.pipe(writeStream);